# É certo criar minhas tags HTML?

Tags: html, aplicação-web, estilo-de-codificação

Estou criando um site e não gosto muito de ficar adicionando classes e id's pois acho que isso deixa o HTML um pouco sujo.

O sistema que estou desenvolvendo não será indexado pelos mecanismos de busca, pois trata-se de um pequeno app web que contém uma página privada onde requer *login*. Logo, acho que não há necessidade de utilizar as *tags* do HTML5.

Isto é certo ou poderá haver problemas de incompatibilidade?

Comment: Se quer criar tags personalizadas, pq não parte pro XML ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, precisa saber que não está criando *tag* HTML. HTML é só o que foi definido pela W3C com esta nomenclatura. HTML é um padrão que não permite personalização. Está criando *tags* XML que os navegadores aceitam o uso conjunto por liberalidade de interpretação permitindo que interaja com o DOM no que precisar.

Poderia até ser um site público se precisar de indexação, só deve saber que alguns navegadores podem não entender bem isso (não pode ser coisa muito antiga, tipo IE8).

Precisa saber fazer direito. Pelo exemplo parece que sabe, exceto pelos nomes usados.

Pode sofrer um pouco com a maioria das ferramentas de auxílio ao desenvolvimento que reclamarão das "suas" *tags*. Essa é uma incompatibilidade (por culpa delas, não sua).

Talvez no futuro possa aparecer uma *tag* padrão HTML que use o mesmo nome que usou. Você terá que fazer um *global renaming* da sua para outra coisa. Está ok, pra você? Pra evitar isso recomenda-se que o nome das suas personalizadas sempre tenham um traço (sinal de menos) no nome.

Dentro dessas condições está tudo ok. Vai fundo!

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements). [Draft da tecnologia](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/). [JS útil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement).

[Tutorial interessante sobre o assunto](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não é semântico, tão pouco viável deixar que cada um fique criando tag a torto e direita, conversamos a pouco sobre padrão de nomenclatura, se eu tivesse vontade de usar o mesmo padrão em HTML teríamos `<titulo>` ao invés de `<h1>` que já é indicado pra isso, por exemplo,  `<sub_titulo>`,`<texto>`,`<texto_data>`,`<texto_autor>` que poderia ser uma tag básica e que já existe e que receberia uma classe pra ser tratada diferente. Dificulta o compreendimento do próximo, se distancia dos padrões e sinceramente a W3C deve ficar de cabelos em pé com isso.

Comment: Por isso eles garantiram que nunca vão criar *tags* com traços no nome e criaram o mecanismo para ser usado quando a pessoa souber o que está fazendo. Pra ser, justamente, mais semântico. Alguém pode abusar disto? Pode. Como tudo pode. è bom explicar para o pessoal do AngularJS que eles fizeram errado.

Comment: Como o @bigown falou, fiquei em dúvida quanto ao Angular JS. Vejo algumas tags que não são do HTML.